# 'Error deserializing object from entity stream' after submitting a multipart/form-data using JavaScript/AJAX to JAX-RS backend

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, blob

I am developing a RESTful webapp with a JavaScript frontend and JAX-RS backend with Netbeans 8.2 so far all has been working great. I have a form where a user uploads his image and i would like to save this image as a blob in my database ( i know the shortcomings but i'd like to proceed this way). Please see the snippets below.

First, the POST request on form submit:

```
 var file = URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById("candidatePicture").files[0]);


    fetch(file).then(response => {
        response.blob().then(photo => {

            const reader = new FileReader();

            // Start reading the blob as text.
            reader.readAsText(photo);

            // This fires after the blob has been read/loaded.
            reader.addEventListener('loadend', (e) => {

                const text = e.srcElement.result;
                var ballotData = $("#addBallotForm").serializeArray();
                var ballot = {
                    "candidateName": ballotData[0].value,
                    "positionName": ballotData[1].value,
                    "candidateNIC": ballotData[2].value,
                    "partyname": ballotData[3].value,
                    "candidateSlogan": ballotData[4].value,
                    "candidatePicture": text,
                    "actionPlan": ""
                };
                console.log(JSON.stringify(ballot));

                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    crossDomain: true,
                    type: "POST",
                    enctype: 'application/json',
                    processData: false, // Important! prevent jQuery from transforming the data into a query string 
                    cache: false,
                    url: url,
                    data: JSON.stringify(ballot)
                }).done((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
                    if (jqXHR.status === 200) {
                        swal("The ballot has been succesfully created!", {icon: "success"})
                                .then((confirm) => {
                                    if (confirm) {
                                        table.ajax.reload();
                                        clearAddBallotModal(); // clear the form
                                        $("#addBallotModal").click(); // close the modal
                                        displayBallots(); // redisplay the ballots
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        swal("Oops! Invalid ballot Input", {icon: "warning"});
                    }
                }).fail((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                    swal("Error! An error occured!", {icon: "error"});
                });

            });

        });
    });
```

Second, the resource endpoint:

```
 @POST
@Path("{ipaddress}/{electionid}")
@ApiOperation(value = "Create new ballot item", notes = "This can only be done by logged in users.")
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid ballot item Input"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Ballot item created")})
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response add(
        @ApiParam(value = "The ipaddress of the ballot item to be created", required = true) @PathParam("ipaddress") String ip,
        @ApiParam(value = "The election's id", required = true) @PathParam("electionid") String electionid,
        @ApiParam(value = "The ballot item that needs to be added", required = true) BallotItem newBallot) {

    Users curUser = UsersService.find(1l); 
    Election election = electionService.find(Long.parseLong(electionid));
    newBallot.setElectionID(election);
    ballotsService.create(newBallot);
    operationsService.create(new Operation(curUser, "Created a new ballot item", "Candidate name: " + newBallot.getCandidateName() + " and Election ID: " + electionid, new Date(), ip));
    return Response.ok(newBallot).build();
}
```

I get the following error in netbeans console:

```
Severe:   javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal.JsonBindingProvider.readFrom(JsonBindingProvider.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:257)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1093)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:98)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:75)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:704)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1628)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:755)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Internal error: Event START_ARRAY not found. Last data: [EVENT: START_OBJECT KEY_NAME: candidatePicture]
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonbRiParser.moveTo(JsonbRiParser.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractArrayDeserializer.moveToFirst(AbstractArrayDeserializer.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserializeInternal(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectDeserializer.deserializeNext(ObjectDeserializer.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserializeInternal(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserialize(Unmarshaller.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.deserialize(JsonBinding.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.fromJson(JsonBinding.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal.JsonBindingProvider.readFrom(JsonBindingProvider.java:99)
    ... 60 more
```

I changed `'application/json'` to `'mulitpart/form-data'` and `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` to other mediatypes but all i got was a `415` error in my browser console as response. Please does anyone has ideas to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like an array is expected as a value of candidatePicture but there's only a text value in the JSON data. What's the value of e.srcElement.result? Can you share the code of BallotItem?

Comment: @OndroMih here is the value of e.srcElement.result
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t_qIojtR3YUPXDlAbtf01AGrodjvnfCv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @OndroMih And here is the class of BallotItem
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19sfTGDgyTVNYAcjm0VOLikmoOFChLfex

Answer (score 4):

JSONB supports deserializing byte arrays. The problem is your particular use case.

By default BYTE encoding is used. In this case your `candidatePicture` property should be an array and look similar to this:

```
"candidatePicture":[89,97,115,115,111,110,32,105,115,32,112,101,114,102,101,99,116,33]
```

I see that it's not your case.

If BASE_64 encoding is used, which is kinda standard, you should tell JSONB engine to use it in custom configuration:

```
JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig()
                .withBinaryDataStrategy(BinaryDataStrategy.BASE_64);
Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.newBuilder()
                .withConfig(config)
                .build();
jsonb.fromJson(...);
```

In this case your property should be a BASE_64 encoded string and look like this:

```
"candidatePicture":"WWFzc29uIGlzIHBlcmZlY3Qh"
```

I guess that this is your case, but your string doesn't look like BASE_64 encoded though. Try it, if doesn't work check what encoding you use to encode your binary data.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry for your answer. Please I need some further clarification. candidatePicture property should be an array of what?  integers? Also, I used BASE_64 once but the form took a long time to submit. So I decided to convert the blob image to text. Supposing I decide to use BASE_64 encoding, please where do i tell JSONB engine to use BASE_64 in custom configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the constructor is default empty constructor is declared as public and not default

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your `BallotItem` class contains field `byte[] candidatePicture`, which JSON binding doesn't know how to set from the incoming JSON by default. The JSON just contains a string with binary data (I'm not sure whether this is encoded with base64). A Jakarta EE Server tries to save the string into a byte array and fails.

This might be a bug in your Jakarta EE server or this may not be specified. The JSON-Binding specification http://json-b.net/ doesn't mention how this should work. It only specifies that a byte array is converted to JSON using the "byte" strategy by default, but no mention about how binary data is converted from JSON.

I suggest adding a custom deserializer to your field `candidatePicture` in `BallotItem` with [JsonbTypeDeserializer](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/bind/annotation/JsonbTypeDeserializer.html). That should work but requires a few lines of code to implement.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation; it makes a lot of sense. I'll try with JsonbTypeDeserializer and let you know of it works.

Comment: I couldn't find any use case of JsonbTypeDeserializer over the internet. Seems like no one has ever had this issue?